How to wait for response of an async function in Swift
When running the following code, my function returns empty array for the function fetchProfilesForList.
That is because the function does not wait for the completion of fetching the profiles before returning.
How do I change the following code to wait for a response for the async function?
ViewModel
func addNoteToList(title: String, note: String) {

    if let id = self.listID {

        if let userID = profileID {
            fm.fetchProfile(uid: userID, completion: { [self] profile in
                print("FETCHED USER PROFILE FOR SHORTCUT")
                
                fm.fetchList(uid: id, completion: { [self] list in
                    print("FETCHED LIST FOR SHORTCUT")
                    
                    
                    fetchProfilesForList(list: List, completion: { profiles in
                        print("users retuned \(profiles.count)")

                        for p in profiles {
                            print("ADD NOTE TO LIST SHORTCUT")
                            
                            //Create LIST
                            let note = Payment(
                                title: title, note: note, user: p.uid )
                            
                            //Add payment to home
                            var l = list
                            l.notes.append(note)
                            self.fm.updateList(l)
                            
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    }
}

func fetchProfilesForList(list: List, completion: @escaping ([Profile]) -> Void) {

    var group: [Profile] = []
                
        if list.admin != profileID && list.group.contains(profileID!) {
            print("IS NOT ADMIN and add to note")
            
            fm.fetchProfile(uid: home.admin, completion: { admin in
                print("FETCHED ADMIN")
                
                people.append(admin)
            })
        }
        
        
        for p in list.group {
            print("P IN GROUP")
            
            if p != profileID! {
                // Fetch profile
                fm.fetchProfile(uid: p, completion: { profile in
                    print("profile \(profile.firstName)")
                    
                    group.append(profile)
                })
            }
        }

    let users = group.removeDuplicates() // incase fetched twice
    
    completion(p) // RETURNS BEFORE PROFILES ARE FETCHED

}

Firestore Manager
public class FirestoreManager {

let db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchList(uid: String, completion: @escaping (Home) -> Void) {
    db.collection("lists").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            do {
                let l = try document.data(as: List.self)
                completion(l)
            }
            catch {
                print("There was an error getting decoding List")
            }
            
        } else {
            print("Document for List
 \(uid) does not exist")
        }
    }
}

func fetchProfile(uid: String, completion: @escaping (Profile) -> Void) {
    
    db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
         if let document = document, document.exists {
            do {
                let p = try document.data(as: Profile.self)
                completion(p)
            }
            catch {
              print("There was an error getting decoding Profile")
            }
            
         } else {
            print("Document for users / profile does not exist")
        }
     }
}


Use a DispatchGroup with group.enter()/group.leave(), or change the completion to async/await.

Swift to async/await. Firestore has compatible versions for almost everything.

This is happening because there are multiple asynchronous fetch calls are being made. Since they are async calls, and the main function's completion gets called before the fetch requests return the data back.
There are two ways to fix this issue -

Using DispatchGroup to wait for all the async calls to finish before calling the main function's completion.
Using async/await if your project can support minimum required version for that.

Using DispatchGroup -
func fetchProfilesForList(list: List, completion: @escaping ([Profile]) -> Void) {
    var group: [Profile] = []
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    if list.admin != profileID && list.group.contains(profileID!) {
        print("IS NOT ADMIN and add to note")
        // Enters in dispatch group
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        fm.fetchProfile(
            uid: home.admin,
            completion: {
                admin in
                print("FETCHED ADMIN")
                group.append(admin)  // Assuming, you are appending to "group here instead of "people"
                // Leaves the group
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        )
    }
    
for p in list.group {
    print("P IN GROUP")
    if p != profileID! {
        // Fetch profile
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        fm.fetchProfile(
            uid: p,
            completion: {
                profile in
                print("profile \(profile.firstName)")
                group.append(profile)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        )
    }
}
    
// It gets called only when all the calls leave DispatchGroup
// So it will wait for all the async calls to complete
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    let users = group.removeDuplicates()  // incase fetched twice
    completion(users)  // Assuming you want to return "users" here instead of "p"
}
}

Using async/await -
The ayntax of async/await is natural and much cleaner than callbacks. If you want to use async/await, you will have to convert your callback functions to async functions using either withContinuation or withCheckedContinuation in this case.
You can convert your callback functions to async like this -
func fetchProfile(uid: String) async -> Profile? {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                do {
                    let profile = try document.data(as: Profile.self)
                    continuation.resume(returning: profile)
                } catch {
                    print("There was an error decoding Profile")
                    continuation.resume(returning: nil)
                }
            } else {
                print("Document for users / profile does not exist")
                continuation.resume(returning: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

and use them like this
func fetchProfilesForList(list: List) async -> [Profile] {
    var group: [Profile] = []

    if list.admin != profileID && list.group.contains(profileID!) {
        print("IS NOT ADMIN and add to note")
        
        if let admin = await fetchProfile(uid: list.admin) {
            print("FETCHED ADMIN")
            group.append(admin)
        }
    }

    for p in list.group {
        print("P IN GROUP")
        
        if p != profileID!, let profile = await fetchProfile(uid: p) {
            print("profile \(profile.firstName)")
            group.append(profile)
        }
    }

    let users = group.removeDuplicates() // In case fetched twice
    
    return users
}

